# Can an LVM Dynamically Allocate Reserved Space to its Volumes?

Tags: rhel, lvm

I am installing RHEL on a few systems and found an interesting option for LMVs.

> [volgroup (optional)](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/sect-kickstart-syntax.html#idp53804720)
>
> Creates a Logical Volume Management (LVM) group.
>
> --reserved-space= - Specify an amount of space to leave unused in a volume group in MiB. Applicable only to newly created volume groups.
>
> --reserved-percent= - Specify a percentage of total volume group space to leave unused. Applicable only to newly created volume groups.

Now I'm wondering the utility of `--reserved-percent`. I understand the premise, many times I've encountered disks where a single partition is full and another has tons of space.

I'm wondering if there's a way to dynamically allocate the reserved space to volumes as they fill?

Comment: you mean thin volumes?

Comment: Thanks, that was enough to set me on the right track using the RHEL Logical Volume Administration Guide: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/LV.html#thinly_provisioned_volume_creation